# Django:Querying database

Tags: python, database, django, pagination

I have this model

```
class messages(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        (u'read',u'read'),
        (u'unread',u'unread')
        )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=status_choices,default='unread')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="sender")
```

Now I want to fetch only first 10 messages that belong "user1",on the second request next 10 messages and so on.How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides this functionality already with a [`Paginator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) object. In your URL you'll need a `page` parameter that says on which page you are and in your view you need to construct a `Paginator` object. You need to specify the number of objects on a page (in your case 10) and the `Paginator` will do the rest.

For example, the following code will print all instances that are displayed on page 3:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

objects = messages.objects.all()
p = Paginator(objects, 10)
page3 = p.page(3)
print page3.object_list
```

The documentation gives examples on how to implement your views and how to pass the list of objects to your template.

Comment: Okay,I have the doubt regarding this pagination thing.Does request for  some page triggers database access or database is accessed only one time i.e. at the creation of pagination object.

Comment: don't have doubts. Paginator is Awesome. Django querysets are lazy. `messages.objects.all()` doesn't call the DB until its evaluation is accessed by paginator. essentially, one call to the DB per request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all 2 things

- your model should have be capitalized (convention)
- "Messages" is part of the contrib package and **without namespacing** will throw a conflict when trying to use both contrib's Message and your app's Message (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages)

#### EDIT

removed my code example, bumping Simeon Visser's solution

Comment: `Message` is not reserved. It's used by the Django messages contrib package, yes, but you can still use it in your own apps. That's where module namespacing comes into play. If you need to use Django's Message, you just don't dump into the global namespace, but instead do something like `from django.contrib.messages import models as messages_models` and then use `messages_models.Message` in your code. If you couldn't use a class name just because someone else created some package somewhere that uses the same class names, we'd be out of class names.

Comment: @Chris Pratt: Thanks for catching that, I misspoke. I do however still think that to avoid confusion and increase maintainability its best not to reuse classnames that represent core framework Classes. I would name it something like PrivateMessage or UserMessage or some variation. Yes this is what namespacing is for, but at some point you lose clarity when quickly trying to digest code.

Comment: Well, sure, you could have a whole other debate over whether you *should* or not, and I pretty much agree with you there actually: I don't think you should do it if it's avoidable. On the other hand, it's also important to point out that contrib packages are marked as contrib for a reason. It's perfectly acceptable to not use them at all and to use another library entirely for the same purpose. In which case, you probably will end up using the same class name.